# Wordpress Alphabetical Glossary close div in loop

Tags: loop

wrote this piece of code to make a alphabetical glossary and it works, but there is 1 problem. I don't know how I can end a set of posts with the same first letter.

This code looks at the first letter of the second word (this is for my project) and then it makes a heading with that first letter and places all the matching lines under that. But after that I want to close this set with an `</div>` (and open it first off course). But if I put the close div in my loop, the code places a `</div>` after each line.

So I need something that says: Close div after last line with the matching first letter. And then open a new div and do it again.

Hope you understand what I need. Thank you.

```
    <?php
     $obj = get_queried_object();
     $post_type = $obj->name;

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => $post_type,
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'posts_per_page' => 20,
    );

    query_posts($args);

    if (have_posts()) : $curr_letter = ''; while (have_posts()) : the_post();

    $title = get_the_title();
    $title_array = explode(' ', $title);
    $second_word = $title_array[1];

    $this_letter = substr($second_word, 0, 1);

    if ($this_letter != $curr_letter) {

    $curr_letter = $this_letter; ?> 

        <div id="sort-<?php echo strtolower($this_letter); ?>" class="alpha_title">
            <?php echo $this_letter; ?>
        </div><!--End alpha_title-->

    <?php } ?>

    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo $second_word; ?></a>

    <?php endwhile; endif; ?> 

    <div class="clear"></div>

</div><!--End glossary-->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you search the site, most of the "display nth post different" questions are very closely related to this one, and honestly this is more a PHP + logic question that a WordPress one.

```
if (have_posts()) { 
  $curr_letter = ''; 
  echo '<div class="alphawrapper">';
    while (have_posts()) {
      the_post();
      $title = get_the_title();
      $title_array = explode(' ', $title);
      $second_word = $title_array[1];
      $this_letter = substr($second_word, 0, 1);
      if ($this_letter != $curr_letter) {
        if (!empty($curr_letter)) {
          echo '</div><div class="alphawrapper">';
        }
        $curr_letter = $this_letter; ?> 
        <div id="sort-<?php echo strtolower($this_letter); ?>" class="alpha_title">
          <?php echo $this_letter; ?>
        </div><!--End alpha_title--><?php 
      } ?>
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo $second_word; ?></a><?php
    }
  echo '</div>';
}
```

However, ***do not use `query_posts`***. There are a thousand "tutorials" online recommending it, including parts of the Codex, but don't use it.

> It should be noted that using this to **replace the main query** on a page
>   can **increase page loading times**, in worst case scenarios **more than
>   doubling the amount of work needed or more**. While easy to use, the
>   function is also **prone to confusion and problems** later on. See the
>   note further below on caveats for details.
>
> http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts (emphasis mine)

Use a filter on `pre_get_posts` instead. In your theme's `functions.php` put:

```
function pregp_wpse_110875($qry) {
  if ($qry->is_main_query() && $qry->is_archive()) {
    $qry->set('posts_per_page',20);
    $qry->set('orderby','title');
    $qry->set('order','ASC');
  }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','pregp_wpse_110875');
```

Comment: Okay thank you. So I should place it on Stackoverflow? And if I don't use query_posts, how can I modify the posts_per_page for different archive pages?

Comment: There is no reason to put this on [SO]. It is perfectly on topic here. See the edit.

Comment: @s_ha_dum - This worked great! Thanks. Only one issue I'm having: Apparently I have one post that starts with a lowercase 'r'. The loop is creating a separate group for this one that's lowercase, separate from the others that start with a capital 'R'. I'm not sure how to have it recognize them as the same letter and put them all together.

Comment: It has been awhile since I cooked this up, and I haven't tested this suggestion, but it looks like you would need to normalize '$this_letter' something like '$this_letter = strtolower(substr($second_word, 0, 1));', which makes the 'strtolower()' in the html ID redundent and probably means you'd need 'strtoupper()' inside that 'div'

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way you can add a closing div after the last line with the matching first letter:

```
<?php
$obj = get_queried_object();
$post_type = $obj->name;

$args = array(
    'post_type' => $post_type,
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => 20,
);

query_posts($args);

if (have_posts()) : 
    $curr_letter = ''; 
    while (have_posts()) : 
        the_post();

        $title = get_the_title();
        $title_array = explode(' ', $title);
        $second_word = $title_array[1];

        $this_letter = substr($second_word, 0, 1);

        if ($this_letter != $curr_letter) {

            // If this is not the first iteration, close the previous div.
            if ($curr_letter != '') {
                echo '</div>';
            }

            $curr_letter = $this_letter; ?> 

            <div id="sort-<?php echo strtolower($this_letter); ?>" class="alpha_title">
                <?php echo $this_letter; ?>
            </div><!--End alpha_title-->

        <?php } ?>

        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo $second_word; ?></a>

    <?php endwhile;

    // Close the div after the last iteration.
    echo '</div>';

endif; ?>
```

In this code, after the first letter heading is printed, a div is opened. Then, for each subsequent line with the same first letter, the link is printed inside that div. When a line with a different first letter is encountered, the previous div is closed and a new one is opened for the new letter. Finally, after the last iteration, the div is closed.