# How can I show my post under a certain content name?

Tags: posts

I want to know how can I show my detail post under that post name. When I post something under a category it shows up with the description of that post in the category, there is no problem with it, when I posted my second post it shows up also with the description of my second post but I have to scroll down to my page to see the posts i made because both of the post shows up with their descriptions.

I want to know how can I hyperlink my post name so that visitors can see my posts name sequentially as hyper-linked and my all descriptions and post content which is under the post name will appear after clicking my post name.

**As example:**

Suppose I made three post which titled are "A", "B" and "C", in my page I want to show only the title sequentially as "A", "B" and "C" and after clicking on any of the title name it will show its description. I hope you will understand what I am trying to say.

Comment: Are you looking for an alphabetical index? Something like this: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/110884/21376 ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit your theme's category.php file (or archive.php if you don't have a category.php file). You need to remove the `the_excerpt()` or `the_content()` line, whichever is present there.