# Grouping posts starting with same letter

Tags: sort

I have a CPT called `authors`. Titles include first and last names. To alphabetically sort these posts by surname I use [this filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16416217/wordpress-orderby-last-word-in-title):

```
function posts_orderby_lastname ($orderby_statement) 
{
  $orderby_statement = "RIGHT(post_title, LOCATE(' ', REVERSE(post_title)) - 1) DESC";
    return $orderby_statement;
}
```

Now I need to group posts with surnames starting with the same letter under one same heading "A", "B"... "Z". I know how to do this looking at the first letter of the post title, but how to do it with the first letter of the surname in my case?

Comment: What is the context? Is this the main query? A secondary query?

Comment: Your question is probably a duplicate of this one, in principle: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/110875/21376

Comment: Wow you're awesome, your solution on this link works perfectly.

Comment: Feel free to upvote anytime, anywhere :)